# How to implement user messages window in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement user messages window in the home page of my application.
I want to notify the application users of events and activities taking place at the university on a specific date. 
I add an image where the window I want to make is marked in purple :)
There is Widget in Flutter that supports it? or how I can implement it?[image]
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple routes you could go here you could implement Firebase FCM messaging but I think this is overkill for what you are trying to do you probably want to go with flutter local notification I will post a link below. As for outlining it in purple this is very easy.

```
Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple, width: 5.0),
        ),
      ),
```

If you are not using a container something similar can be done with most widgets let me know if I can help you further
[Flutter Local Notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)